# Clickable Link to Custom Route from Google Maps web to iOS app

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios

My first question here. I'm hoping I'm doing the tags and such correctly so the right folks might be able to see this. If this question should be placed in other area, please let me know.

I'm trying to create a link to a set of custom driving directions that, when clicked from the native iOS Mail app, will open the Google Maps iOS app and populate the custom directions.

I have a map which has driving directions from Point A to Point B, but I've significantly revised the route using the click and re-position functionality in Google Maps (web).

Using the share function from Google Maps (web) creates a link that does in fact retain the custom route, which can be seen when the link is clicked and it opens  in Safari. I don't mind that it opens in Safari, since at this point it prompts you to open up these directions in the Google Maps app. But here's where it gets muddy.

When you click the "use the app" button from Safari, the custom route does not carry over to the app. You are shown default route choices based on Point A and B.

The [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Waypoints) section on Waypoints and using the 'via:' prefix seems like the best way around this, but I'm not sure how I'd turn that into something clickable from an email.

For reference, [here is one of the maps](https://goo.gl/maps/BNtz4) I made with a custom route. Basically I want to have it go from Point A to B along one road. I had to make a handful of points along the route in order to keep the route on the same stretch of road.

Further complicating this is Google's attempt to reroute even this map, based on real-time traffic. I went back to this link after copying it here to find out there's an accident on this road right now and it's re-routing through side streets.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: super late response but thanks everyone for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can open the google maps as it follow as it is documented in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme#directions):

```
comgooglemaps://?saddr=Google,+1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA+94043&daddr=Google+Inc,+345+Spear+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&center=37.422185,-122.083898&zoom=10
```

However, there is no mention on how you can add waypoints. And, indeed, you can not even do it in the Maps App. So there is basically nothing we can do...

BTW, here is a [blog](http://www.macworld.com/article/2687984/how-to-create-multi-destination-map-routes-on-your-iphone.html) where included some work arounds, hope this helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

here is what i do : long method, but it works.
open google my maps (instead of google maps) and make your custom route.
in options, export your route to KML/KMZ
at gps vizualizer com, convert your route to the format your app accepts.